# Can't get KEY_UP with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

i am trying to make a simple program to detect the UP key. here is my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {

    initscr();
    noecho();

    printw("hello\n");
    refresh();

    int ch = getch();
    if (ch == KEY_UP) {
        printw("up!\n");
        refresh();
    }

    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile and run the program, it doesn't work. when i press up key it just exits.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `keypad` to tell curses to interpret special keys:

```
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

after `initscr()`.  Without that, your program will read (separately) <kbd>escape</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd>.

Further reading:

- [Initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) (ncurses manual)
- [keypad(3)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad)

Comment: it works! when i press up key it prints "up!" but then when i press another key (including up key) it exists. any ideas?

Comment: Your program only does two calls for `getch`, and will exit after the second call.  Also, you might want to call `cbreak`.