# wgetch is not detecting KEY_UP etc

Tags: ncurses, curses

I have enabled keypad for my_win and yet when I press KEY_UP after running the program, nothing happens. The stranger thing is that it works completely fine with stdscr. It appears to only be an issue with my_win.

```
/* Selects different elements of the list */
    while ((ch = wgetch(my_win)) != 'q')
    {
        sprintf(item, "%-12s", list[i]);
        mvwprintw(my_win, i + 1, 2, "%s", item);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case KEY_LEFT:
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, starty,--startx);
                wprintw(my_win, "This is some text");
                wrefresh(my_win);
                break;
            case 'd':
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, starty,++startx);
                wprintw(my_win, "This is some text");
                wrefresh(my_win);
                break;
            case 'w':
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, --starty,startx);
                wprintw(my_win, "This is some text");
                wrefresh(my_win);
                break;
            case 's':
                destroy_win(my_win);
                my_win = create_newwin(height, width, ++starty,startx);
                wprintw(my_win, "This is some text");
                wrefresh(my_win);
                break;  
            case KEY_UP:
                i--;
                i = (i < 0) ? 4 : i;
                break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                i++;
                i = (i < 0) ? 4 : i;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: `getch()` and friends is really not that great a tool. You probably want to hook in with a lower-level OS function to get all keyboard events.

Comment: What functions do you suggest?

Comment: Depends 100% on your operating system.

Comment: I'm running linux at the moment

Comment: Are you writing a console mode program (Running in a terminal window) or a GUI program? What you ask is much easier with Windows than Linux.

Comment: This seems to be closely related: [Can't get KEY_UP with ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35673131/2402272).

Comment: If indeed you are using ncurses, as it sure appears you are doing, then please add that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`keypad`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) function applies only to the window given as its parameter.  When you use `newwin`, etc., those return a window where the keypad mode is not set.

The [**`newwin`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-newwin) documentation points out

> Regardless of the function  used  for  creating  a  new  window  (e.g.,
> **`newwin`**, **`subwin`**, **`derwin`**, **`newpad`**), rather than a duplicate (with dupwin),
> all of the window modes are initialized to the default  values.   These
> functions set window modes after a window is created:
>
> ```
> idcok, idlok, immedok, keypad, leaveok, nodelay, scrollok,
> setscrreg, syncok, wbkgdset, wbkgrndset, and wtimeout
> ```